# using robocopy to mirror folders as a scheduled task without users logged in

Tags: windows, robocopy

I have two servers, one local user with the same password and username. It will always be a one-way transfer serverA --> serverB.

I created a scheduled task that runs (on serverB)

```
robocopy \\serverA.domain.gov\datastore c:\datastore /MIR
```

The user has Run as a batch service as recommended by the MSDN site and the task always fails.
The user has RX access on serverA and full access (other than list) on serverB.
When I run the command manually in a cmdbox (as the local user) it says access denied but I'm not really sure why. When I run robocopy manually, it says robocopy does not have rights to c:\datastore but it does!

Comment: It appears it needs complete/full control and not having the list prevents it from operating properly. the question can be considered answered.

Comment: It wouldn't let me--it said I had to wait 8 hours.